# Repeated measures, mixed model ANCOVA in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset, which consists of 44 subjects, each of whom have either 2, 3, or 4 measurements (i.e. not every subject has an equal number of measurements). I have two categorical variables that largely vary between subjects, but sometimes within subject. Subject age is also included in the dataset as a covariate for the measurements, as it varies between measurements for an individual subject.

Questions of interest: How do the independent variables affect our dependent variable? Does age also affect our dependent variable? This is somewhat two-fold, in that age varies within subject, but then also between subjects as well.

What is the best way to code/model this kind of data? I've tried the following, but this does not seem to return the appropriate result.

```
aov(DV ~ Age + IV1 + IV2 + Error(1/SubjectID), data = df)
```

Here is some sample data.

```
df <-data.frame(Subject = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9,10,10,11,11,11,12,12,12,12,13,13,13,13,14,14,14,14,15,15,15,15,16,16,16,16,17,17,17,17,18,18,18,18,19,19,19,19,20,20,20), IV1 = c(1,3,2,2,1,3,2,3,1,4,1,3,1,3,2,2,1,2,1,3,2,4,4,2,2,3,4,1,2,4,4,1,3,3,5,1,3,3,4,1,3,3,5,1,3,3,4,2,2,4,4,1,2,4,4,2,3,4), IV2 = c(2,2,3,3,2,2,3,3,2,2,1,1,3,3,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,2,1,1),Age = c(10,12,11,12,9,10,10,12,10,13,9,10,9,10,10,11,10,11,9,10,11,13,14,10,11,12,13,10,11,12,13,9,10,11,12,9,10,11,12,9,10,11,12,9,10,11,12,10,11,12,13,10,11,12,13,12,13,14),DV = c(209,173,181,113,178,166,368,68,133,24,232,182,77,59,263,235,68,44,254,263,270,203,75,99,200,118,142,174,528,340,325,145,97,57,134,97,203,141,72,294,217,159,115,131,82,206,65,637,471,139,195,114,273,392,271,239,141,228))
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be wrong but I think this is more of a cross-validated question, rather than stackoverflow which deals primarily with coding.

Regarding the question - it would be really helpful if you uploaded some sample data so people can have a try and see what it looks like. At a guess, without seeing the sample data, you may not want an ANCOVA. ANCOVAs/ANOVAs are quite sensitive to unbalanced designs (i.e. unequal sampling designs). When you say each one has multiple measures that were repeated 2, 3, or 4 times do you mean that some subjects had more measures than others? Do different ages represent the repeated measures?

If so, you might try this:

```
library(lme4)
dv.lmer <- lmer(DV ~ IV1 + IV2 + (1|SubjectID/Age), data = df) 
summary(dv.lmer)
```

What is the DV response variable?

Also, have you ruled out any kind of interaction effects (i.e. are they outside the scope of your project)?

EDIT:

An ANCOVA would definitely be inappropriate for these data given the difference in number of samples and the unequal gaps between re-measurement I am afraid. In fact, this makes it quite difficult to model with any standard approach, at least in this format.

You could create a new Age variable that simplifies Age down to which measurement it was (i.e. first, second or third). From there you could try something like a mixed effect model. Catch is you are losing any age or time between remeasurement information.

Another alternative would be to take the difference between time points I.e. for subject 13 take the difference of all the variables. However, this would reduce your data down to just the first two time points, as you would otherwise be back in repeated measures territory....

It comes down to what your question of interest is.

I might be able to help more if you put the data into a format that I can easily import to R (e.g. df <- data.frame(DV = c(), IV1 = c(), etc....) ). This link (https://www.r-bloggers.com/three-tips-for-posting-good-questions-to-r-help-and-stack-overflow/) is a good place to start!

EDIT 2:
Here is one approach to the problem, although the inferences one can make are limited because of the observational nature of the study and the confounding factors implicit in these data. It's a pretty common issue with human studies (and ecological data which I often deal with). That is not to say that you can't draw correlations and patterns, but that you should be careful how you present these results. Below is one possibility but it really does come back to the question you want to ask the data as to whether the model is correct...

Feel free to ask if anything is unclear!

```
 #Corrections
 df$Subject <- as.character(df$Subject)

 #Creating new sample time points
 df$SampleTime <- 0 

 uniSubject <- unique(df$Subject)

 #filling vector
 for(i in 1:length(uniSubject)){

   df[df$Subject == uniSubject[i],]$SampleTime <- 1:nrow(df[df$Subject == 
 uniSubject[i],])

 }


 #Modelling
 library(lme4)


 #Interaction model
 DVint.lmer <- lmer(DV ~ IV1 * IV2 + (1 + SampleTime|Subject), data = df)
 summary(DVint.lmer)

 #Additive model
 DVadd.lmer <- lmer(DV ~ IV1 + IV2 + (1 + SampleTime|Subject), data = df)
 summary(DVadd.lmer)

 #Comparing models to see if interaction is importnat
 anova(DVint.lmer, DVadd.lmer) #Interaction does not explain any 
 significant variation at the 0.05 level in these data. Parsimony 
 suggests using DVadd.lmer model
```

EDIT:

Given the last comment regarding the importance of Age as a fixed effect, I think this will be closest to the mark:

```
 DVint.lmer <- lmer(DV ~ IV1 * IV2 * Age + (1 + Age|Subject), data = df)
```

Be careful when interpreting, as these are very messy data.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've now included some sample data. We have not ruled out interaction effects, but I want to make sure I have a handle on how to model/code the Age term first.

Comment: I've added the code for the sample data to be executed in R. Appreciate the help

Comment: See above edit - if it answers the original question please do give it a tick. Otherwise let me know what is missing.

Comment: Age is a key factor for the analysis, so unfortunately simplifying it down is not really an option. The observational nature of this data does make generating an appropriate model particularly difficult.

Comment: In that case you can try something like `DVint.lmer <- lmer(DV ~ IV1 * IV2 * Age + (1 + Age|Subject), data = df)`  - It is probably the best bet as it incorporates the subject specific changes through time will using including Age as a fixed effect. Regardless of how you model this I don't think you can make any real inferences from it but hopefully you will get a pattern that is somewhat meaningful. Just be careful in your interpretation. EDIT: Maybe go through backward elimination to get rid of insignificant interactions one by one.